# How to implement custom Keras ordinal loss function with tensor evaluation without disturbing TF>2.0 Model Graph?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, ranking, ordinal

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Tensorflow 2.4 using the Keras backend.

The loss function is a ranking loss; I found the following paper with a somewhat log-likelihood loss: [Chen et al. Single-Image Depth Perception in the Wild](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03901.pdf#section.4).

Similarly, I wanted to sample some (in this case 50) points from an image to compare the relative order between ground-truth and predicted depth maps using the NYU-Depth dataset. Being a fan of Numpy, I started working with that but came to the following exception:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: [...]
```

I have learned that this is caused by the arguments not being filled when calling the loss function but instead, a C function is compiled which is then used later. So while I know the dimensions of my tensors (4, 480, 640, 1), I cannot work with the data as wanted and have to use the keras.backend functions on top so that in the end (if I understood correctly), there is supposed to be a path between the input tensors from the TF graph and the output tensor, which has to provide a gradient.

So my question now is: Is this a feasible loss function within keras?
I have already tried a few ideas and different approaches with different variations of my original code, which was something like:

```
def ranking_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # Chen et al. loss

    y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
    y_pred_np = K.eval(y_pred)
    
    if y_true_np.shape[0] != None:
        num_sample_points = 50
        total_samples = num_sample_points ** 2
        
        err_list = [0 for x in range(y_true_np.shape[0])]

        for i in range(y_true_np.shape[0]):
            sample_points = create_random_samples(y_true, y_pred, num_sample_points)
            for x1, y1 in sample_points:
                for x2, y2 in sample_points:
                    if y_true[i][x1][y1] > y_true[i][x2][y2]:
                        #image_relation_true = 1
                        err_list[i] += np.log(1 + np.exp(-1 * y_pred[i][x1][y1] + y_pred[i][x2][y2]))
                    elif y_true[i][x1][y1] < y_true[i][x2][y2]:
                        #image_relation_true = -1
                        err_list[i] += np.log(1 + np.exp(y_pred[i][x1][y1] - y_pred[i][x2][y2]))
                    else:
                        #image_relation_true = 0
                        err_list[i] += np.square(y_pred[i][x1][y1] - y_pred[i][x2][y2])
        
        err_list = np.divide(err_list, total_samples)
        
        return K.constant(err_list)
```

As you can probably tell, the main idea was to first create the sample points and then based on the existing relation between them in y_true/y_pred continue with the corresponding computation from the cited paper.

Can anyone help me and provide some more helpful information or tips on how to correctly implement this loss using keras.backend functions? Trying to include the ordinal relation information really confused me compared to standard regression losses.

**EDIT:** Just in case this causes confusion: `create_random_samples()` just creates 50 random sample points (x, y) coordinate pairs based on the `shape[1]` and `shape[2]` of `y_true` (image width and height)

**EDIT(2):** After finding [this](https://github.com/Turmac/DIW_TF_Implementation) variation on GitHub, I have tried out a variation using only TF functions to retrieve data from the tensors and compute the output. The adjusted and probably more correct version still throws the same exception though:

```
def ranking_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
#In the Wild ranking loss
y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
y_pred_np = K.eval(y_pred)

if y_true_np.shape[0] != None:
    num_sample_points = 50
    total_samples = num_sample_points ** 2
    
    bs = y_true_np.shape[0]
    w = y_true_np.shape[1]
    h = y_true_np.shape[2]
    
    total_samples = total_samples * bs
    num_pairs = tf.constant([total_samples], dtype=tf.float32)
    
    output = tf.Variable(0.0)

    for i in range(bs):
        sample_points = create_random_samples(y_true, y_pred, num_sample_points)
        for x1, y1 in sample_points:
            for x2, y2 in sample_points:
            
                y_true_sq = tf.squeeze(y_true)
                y_pred_sq = tf.squeeze(y_pred)
            
                d1_t = tf.slice(y_true_sq, [i, x1, y1], [1, 1, 1])
                d2_t = tf.slice(y_true_sq, [i, x2, y2], [1, 1, 1])
                d1_p = tf.slice(y_pred_sq, [i, x1, y1], [1, 1, 1])
                d2_p = tf.slice(y_pred_sq, [i, x2, y2], [1, 1, 1])

                d1_t_sq = tf.squeeze(d1_t)
                d2_t_sq = tf.squeeze(d2_t)
                d1_p_sq = tf.squeeze(d1_p)
                d2_p_sq = tf.squeeze(d2_p)
                
                if d1_t_sq > d2_t_sq:
                    # --> Image relation = 1
                    output.assign_add(tf.math.log(1 + tf.math.exp(-1 * d1_p_sq + d2_p_sq)))
                elif d1_t_sq < d2_t_sq:
                    # --> Image relation = -1
                    output.assign_add(tf.math.log(1 + tf.math.exp(d1_p_sq - d2_p_sq)))
                else:
                    output.assign_add(tf.math.square(d1_p_sq - d2_p_sq))
    
    return output/num_pairs
```

**EDIT(3):** This is the code for create_random_samples():
(FYI: Because it was weird to get the shape from y_true in this case, I first proceeded to hard-code it here as I know it for the dataset which I am currently using.)

```
def create_random_samples(y_true, y_pred, num_points=50):

y_true_shape = (4, 480, 640, 1)
y_pred_shape = (4, 480, 640, 1)

if y_true_shape[0] != None:
    num_samples = num_points
    
    population = [(x, y) for x in range(y_true_shape[1]) for y in range(y_true_shape[2])]
    
    sample_points = random.sample(population, num_samples)
    return sample_points
```

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut for editing my original question! I can clearly understand why you adjusted my wording at some places :)

Comment: Please also provide the codes for create_random_samples().